# Define the s-parameters of 2-port network

Tags: transmission-line

How to define the ***s-parameters*** of the 2-port network below?

I don't know where to start exactly but it is not symmetrical

$$S11 = \frac{V_1+}{V_1-}\ $$

$$S12 = \frac{V_1-}{V_2+}\ $$

$$S21 = \frac{V_2-}{V_1+}\ $$

$$S22 = \frac{V_2+}{V_2-}\ $$

[image: 2 port network device]

Comment: How are your V1+, etc., defined?

Comment: If your V1 etc are voltages at the ports, then you're sort of borrowing the hybrid parameter definition, but using it ignoring current. S parameters work with incident and emerging waves, so you need a radical rethink.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to use your textbook and find the abcd (chain) parameters of a quarter wave transmission line. Then find the abcd parameters of a shunt resistor. The total abcd parameter matrix of the two together is found by multiplying. Then use your text again to find the formula to convert an abcd matrix to an s matrix.